# Testing stubbed callback in associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have two models, linked by simple one-to-many relation.

```
class Device
  has_many :events

  def notify!
    (...)
  end
end

class Event
  after_create :notify_device
  belongs_to :device

  private

  def notify_device
    device.notify!
  end
end
```

`Device#notify!` method has to be stubbed in tests, as in normal flow it triggers communication with device linked via RS-232, which obviously may not be available in test environment (not to mention it shouldn't be notified in tests).

I was trying to set `should_receive` expectation on `device` object created by FactoryGirl, but `device` method used in `Event` class returns different object, which doesn't know about that expectation.

How to write rspec test that would test the fact that `#notify!` is called on proper device?

Comment: Could you show specs code if it is possible?

Comment: I have no proper solution for this problem. Right now test is checking only if method #notify! is called for any_instance of Device, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: But how do you create an Event object?
Are you sure you has mocked device object in Event? https://gist.github.com/1275189

Comment: That might be the problem. I'm using relation for building Event: device.events.create(...)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how to expect message for given AR record. You can either add this feature to rspec, or maybe add some logger to notify! method:

```
class Device

  def notify!(event)
    logger "Device with id '{self.id}' has been notified by event '#{event}'"
  end
end
```

In my opinion such logger may be useful in production, but in test for logging use some mock that you can swap logger to use object you can easily examine in test and check message from notify.

Comment: I was thinking about mocking #notify! method for all instances, to ease up setting expectations, but block passed to mock is run against local binding, and as far as my findings go, there's no way to access device in clean way in this block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `any_instance` should be fine if there is only one device in your test (as a good isolated test should be written).

Or another option is use a callback on Device instead of Event:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :after_add => :notify!

  def notify!
    ...
  end
end
```

That should be much easier to set expectations on:

```
device = Device.new
device.should_receive(:notify!)
device.events << Event.create!
```

Another option I just thought of (but haven't tried) is to stub out the method active record is using to fetch the device during event creation.  Below i'm guessing it is just `Device.find(device.id)` but it might be something else.

```
device = Factory(:device)
device.should_receive(:notify!)
Device.stub(:find).with(device.id) { device }
Event.create!(:device => device)
```

Comment: That is interesting idea to consider, but really -- changing code because of testing suite deficiencies is bad.